# Node.js function with callback dos't run async

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to run a function in a async way, but I always recive the result in the order that i call them instead of receive the quickest function.

This is an example. The expected result is to print first 100 even it is called last.

```
function f1(callback){
    i = 0;
    for (i;i< 100;i++){

    }

    if (i == 100){
        return callback(i);
    }
}

function f2(callback){
    i = 0;
    for (i;i< 99999999999;i++){

    }

    if (i == 99999999999){
        return callback(i);
    }
}

f2(function(i){
    console.log(i);
})

f1(function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node (and in javascript in general), functions are not asynchronous by default.

In your code above, at no point are you yielding control to the javascript's event loop.  As you call each function, it runs through its for loop until finished and then calls back which is why you are seeing the output the way you are.

The asynchronous nature of node kicks in when you start doing IO or purposely yield control to the VM and give it a chance to process other events off the event loop.

To see the code above run in an asynchronous fashion for the purposes of your test:

```
function f1(callback){
    setTimeout(callback('f1'), 100);
}
function f2(callback){
    setTimeout(callback('f2'), 500);
}

f2(function(i){
    console.log(i);
})
f1(function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
```

The `setTimeout` call basically just says: call back to the provided function as close to n milliseconds as you can (but not before).  Basically acting as a sleep statement here and yielding control back to the currently executing code.